# How can I locate this element without using the variant to locate it?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to use selenium to locate this element and click this element, but the variant changes every time. I need selenium to click this button, "M". How can I locate this element without using "33246615686"

```
<label class="radio-label " for="variant-select-33246615686">M</label>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try following `XPath`:

```
//label[text()="M"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text 'M' to find it by xpath:

```
//label[contains(text(),"M")]
```

Comment: probably not a good idea to use contains for this.. you're gonna get all labels with the character 'M', which might be a lot...

Comment: Yep, for this case Andersson's answer is better but is good to know another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
//label[.="M"]
```

you can check this url:

[Avoid using contains(.//text(), ‘search text’) in your XPath conditions. Use contains(., ‘search text’) instead.](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2014/07/17/xpath-tips-from-the-web-scraping-trenches/)

Answer (score 0):

The answers above will work but it is a recipe for fragile code. I avoid using label text as much as possible. A better locator will be:

```
//label[starts-with(@for, 'variant-select')]
```

or

```
//label[contains(@for,'variant-select')]
```

Also, if you will be using this in a localization test for example, it will fail because the text will be written in the locale language the application is set to at the time of testing. For example, the `M` in Chinese will be `米` hence, the `text()` will not see this text. Considering localization in your application ? This is better.